# what is the correct command to reach .php page?

Tags: php

I want line 4 on code to go to page index.php ...
  what is the correct command???

```
if($count==1){
    echo "Welcome...";
    #LINE 4
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. What does "to reach .php page" mean? Do you want to include the content from `index.php`?

Comment: What do you mean with "go" and "reach"? Possible commands are `file_get_contents()`, `header()`, `cURL`, `require()`, `include()`, ...

Comment: Could try die(header('location: index.php'));

Comment: is this script part in index.php or in another page?

Comment: if the condition is true I will open the page index.php

Comment: @Bono if he just redirect, He will never see the "Welcome...".

Comment: @Pier-alexandreBouchard Agreed, but you could just post that on the index.php file.. Anyways it's way unclear what is being asked

Comment: By inccluding it in your page or you want a redirection?

Comment: I agreed with @Bono. You question is really unclear.

Comment: I dont know english. I m sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted some kind of redirection like this :

```
<?php 

if($count==1){
    echo "Welcome...";
    $golink = 'index.php';
   ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>A web page that points a browser to a different page after 2 seconds</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=<?php  echo $golink; ?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="automatic redirection">
</head>
<body>
If your browser doesn't automatically go there within a few seconds, 
you may want to go to 
<a href="<?php echo $golink ?>">the destination</a> 
manually.
</body>
</html>

<?php
    } else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
?>
```

hope this helps !